# Percentages in MySQL - Between two columns in the same table

Tags: mysql, select, insert, percentage

I have a MySQL Table that looks like this:

```
Name    | Pass |  Fail | Pass Percent | Fail Percent

Abdy    | 20   |  5    |              |
Bob     | 10   |  5    |              |
Cantona | 40   |  10   |              |
Dave    | 30   |  20   |              |
```

I am trying to get the percentages:

like : passpercent = (pass/pass+fail)*100

Can I fill the table with a single MySQL code for both the columns??

The Table would look like this hopefully:

```
Name    | Pass |  Fail | Pass Percent | Fail Percent

Abdy    | 20   |  5    |   80         |  20
Bob     | 10   |  5    |   66         |  33
Cantona | 40   |  10   |   80         |  20
Dave    | 30   |  20   |   60         |  40
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's absolutely possible.

To fill the second table:

```
UPDATE mytable SET pass_pct=(pass/pass+fail)*100,fail_pct=(fail/pass+fail)*100
```

Granted, you could also generate those during selection of the first table (if you don't want to store the results), like:

```
SELECT name,pass,fail,(pass/pass+fail)*100 as pass_pct,(fail/pass+fail)*100 as fail_pct FROM mytable
```